# using two JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

using Google analytic

```
  <input type="submit" id="btnTrack" value="Submit!"  onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); return timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'Buni'); " />
```

I am using two function and in this case I want first the `timeTracker._recordEndTime()` executed and then `timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'Buni')`   but I am not getting the expected value

something wrong with this idea?

this is the the idea i am based on

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Latency Tracking Demo</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/time-tracker.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
var timeTracker = new TimeTracker();  
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-1735986-1');   
</script>  
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordStartTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Stop Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Track!" onclick="timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'Manual Test');"/>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from inline event handlers being bad design (in most cases), no, nothing wrong with it. You might want to add more information about your problem if you expect a helpful answer, for example, which result you expect and what actually happens.

Comment: Where do you want to get the value back?

Comment: I have added the base code i used and as you see i want  the last two functions to be called with the second onclick action

Comment: Well, we still don't know what your problem is... Nothing in your code shows any error. You have to debug your code to see where the error is but we cannot do it for you.

Comment: @Felix Kling  the problem was combining the last two onclick events did not work but thanx any how.

Comment: I understand that. But as I said, your code looks correct, which means one can only find the error by running the code and having at the console for example. You are the only one who can run the code, so you have to tell us what happens and what you expect to happen. *Doesn't work* is not a helpful error description.

Answer (score -2):

It only support single statement, not multiple ones, try this:

```
onclick="javascript:(function () { /* try put your multiple statements here. */ })()"
```

Comment: It does support multiple statements: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/LVeyN/ and using `javascript:` in event handlers is unnecessary (who needs the label here?).

Comment: I thought this would be for `href="` `"` ...? This is not for onclick event.